# How to check if these two variables are correlated

Tags: probability-distributions, correlation

I have two variables: A and B

I have a set of N "blocks": 1, 2, 3.... N

For each block I know if A appears or not in that block, for example:

A appears in block 1, A doesn't appear in block 2, ... , A appears in block N.

I have the same data for B, so:

B doesn't appear in block 1, B doesn't appear in block 2, ... , B appears in block N.

How can I check if there's some degree of correlation between the distributions of A and B, to see if they're indipendent or not, possibly with a value that goes from 0 (no correlation) to 1 (they're surely correlated)?

Edit:
the variables A and B are a list of n tokens ∈ N (so the "blocks" are a bigger list of tokens), the presence of A (or B) in 1,2...N is determined by A (or B) sharing the specific token in position 1,2...N.
So for example A = [the, dog, barks, the, cat, is, brown], B = [the, dog, is, brown, and, jumps], N = [the, dog, is, brown, barks, cat, and, jumps, cow, eagle, etc...].
I want to see if there's a correlation between A and B, in terms of shared tokens and of which tokens they're both missing, and viceversa (A has a token but not B).

The position of the token in the list doesn't matter.

Comment: What exactly is the random variable here? Should we be thinking of the $N$ blocks as $N$ i.i.d. samples of two Bernoulli random variables (indicating the presence or absence of $A$, and of $B$)?

Comment: @angryavian the variables A and B are a list of n tokens ∈ N (so the "blocks" are a bigger list of tokens), the presence of A (or B) in 1,2...N is determined by A (or B) sharing the specific token in position 1,2...N.
So for example A = [the, dog, barks, the, cat, is, brown], B = [the, dog, is, brown, and, jumps], N = [the, dog, is, brown, barks, cat, and, jumps, cow, eagle, etc...].
I want to see if there's a correlation between A and B, in terms of shared tokens and of which tokens they're both missing, and viceversa (A has a token but not B).

Comment: The position of the token in the list doesn't matter.

Comment: How is A defined? As shown above, it isn’t random. Is A the first seven tokens in the “block”? How are the blocks created? Are the blocks a list of tokens that are each drawn iid from some distribution?

Comment: @Joe Position of the tokens doesn't matter. A is a subset of N and so is B. N is an arbitrary big set of tokens that for sure includes every token of A and B.

Comment: It’s still not clear to me what random process generates the variables- how are A and B defined. I get that they are lists of tokens from a set of N tokens. It’s somewhat confusing that N is also the number of “blocks”. Here’s why it matters:  if A is a random draw of n tokens from N using some distribution, and B is also an “independent” draw of m tokens from N, then there’s nothing to compute because they are independent by definition. If A and B are generated by some other process, it would be nice if you could explain that process in your question.

Comment: If you have many realizations of A and B, perhaps you want to compute the odds ratio of each token in N: the probability of that token being in A divided by the probability of that token being in B. That ranges from $[0, +\infty]$. Using this approach you would have two binary variables for each token, and an odds ratio of 1 indicates they are independent.